# ApiRequestError when using pydrive in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pydrive

Lately when using pydrive from Google Collab like this

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
import os
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# 1. Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

I enter the code and all but after that i started getting ApiRequestError when trying to create file. In the response i see `Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.`

How do you fix that?

Answer (score 1):

For PyDrive, you'll need to create and use a distinct OAuth client client ID with higher limits. Instructions are here:

https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html#authentication

But, it's probably simpler to use the built-in Drive FUSE client to interact with Drive. To use that, execute a code cell with the following snippet:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

[Details here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA).